# PowerShell IoT-Core only loads .NET modules in interactive mode? How to load explicitly?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10-iot-core

The following windows shellscript.cmd works fine from the Windows 10 IoT-Core command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nop -c "iex(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://container.blob.core.windows.net/api/myps1.ps1')"
```

However, when I start it using the [IoT-ProcessLauncher](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/ProcessLauncherSample.htm) from C#, the Net.WebClient is not found after a pause of about 10 seconds (error below). What do I need to add to my shellscript.cmd script to explicitly set up the proper environment for powershell? I tried loading the assembly explicitly with [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Net.WebClient'); at the beginning of the PS command script but still getting errors. Syntax?

```
    ******************** START Argument Information ********************
Args' Count: 1
     #0: -nop -c iex(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://container.blob.core.windows.net/api/myps1.ps1')
******************** END   Argument Information ********************


.................... START Result  Output ....................
Results Count: 0
.................... END   Result  Output ....................


.................... START Error   Output ....................
Errors Count: 1
     #0:
       - FullyQualifiedId: TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
       -    ExceptionName: System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
       -      InnerExName: null
       -    Error Message: Cannot find type [Net.WebClient]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
       -       StackTrace: Check .\App_path\Stacktrace.txt for more information
System.UnauthorizedAccessException (Check .\log.txt for more information):

Access to the path 'C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Stacktrace.txt' is denied.
```

Comment: That WebClient class is the same System.Net.WebClient used in C#. You don't need to start a Powershell script if you want to call a .NET class

Comment: Thanks. I use Web/HttpClient extensively in C#. That was not the question.